# Validation rule to check on Permission Set and User Profile

Tags: account, validation-rule, permission-sets

I want to create a validation rule on Account object, to lock client name changes by the 'Resource Manager'(This is a permission set). This validation rule should fire when the 'Business User' (This is a profile) edits the client name?

Im trying the following but it looks like the way I reference permission set is wrong.

```
AND(
  $Permission.ResourceManager,
   ISCHANGED(Name),
    $Profile.Name  = "Business User"
)
```

Comment: is Client Name a Custom Field? or  are you referring Client Name as OwnerId?

Comment: sorry yes thats the Client Name, Ive edited that in the code above.

Comment: @DhananjayPatil I came up with this :-                                                   
AND( 
$Profile.Name = 'Business User', 
ISCHANGED( Name ) 
)                                                                                                                            but i'm not sure how to check the permission set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge,You can not add permission set in your validation but you can create a custom permission.Check the below link.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221057&type=1

But I recommend you to use custom setting(Tye:Hierarchy) instead of Permission Sets.In Custom Setting you can create a checkbox field and add the users/profiles whom you want to bypass/enforce the validation rule.Then you add those Custom setting in your validation formula as:

```
$Setup.CustomSettingName__c.CheckboxField__c = False/True(Based on the value you set in custom setting).
```

Its a very easy approach.You can use the same in apex code if you want to bypass those users in future.